# Unexpected behavior of icons inside Bootstrap4 collapse component - can't manage to display icons horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to display 3 icons horizontally inside a Bootstrap4 collapse card. I added the icons (i tags) into the card, but they show vertically. For some reason the i element takes the entire line. Here is a Jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/benCarp/Lz40t409/

I tried changing css properties, including:

```
display: inline; 
width: 20px
```

I also tried changing the parent div to `display: flex`. All of those haven't helped. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Bootstrap 4 `card-body` is `flex-direction:column`. You can change it to `flex-direction:row` using the `flex-row` class...

https://www.codeply.com/go/52ynXc916o

```
<div class="card card-body flex-row">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
```

Or, you can make the card-body `display:block` instead of `display:flex`:

```
<div class="card card-body d-block">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
```

Also as a side note, globally changing the `.col` padding to 10px will have adverse effects on grid alignment.

Comment: Thanks! As for the .col{padding:10px} This css remained from JSfiddle Bootstrap boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the display for the card to be block

```
.card{
  display: block;
}
```

or

```
<div class="card card-body d-block">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
```